# Accessing an array some elements at a time and wrapping round to the beginning

Tags: arrays, iteration, julia

I have a simple question that should have a simple answer but I can't think of it yet. I want to process an array, a certain number of elements at a time, and wrapping round to the beginning.

Here's a diagram showing when `n` is 10 and three elements are wanted each time:

[image: iterations 3 at a time]

My attempts to write a simple iteration so far have failed: using `% n` gives me zeros, which don't work with Julia's one-indexing... :)

Comment: Nice diagram. Usually before doing `% n` you need to subtract 1 and then afterwards add 1 (reminiscent of matrix basis transformation in linear algebra). Also, there are packages which allow 0-based (and other) indexing of arrays, see OffsetArrays (https://github.com/alsam/OffsetArrays.jl).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `mod1` function is provided to allow the behaviour you desire:

```
julia> mod1(1, 5)
1

julia> mod1(3, 5)
3

julia> mod1(5, 5)
5

julia> mod1(6, 5)
1
```

It's pretty straightforward to make a mod-indexed function:

```
modindex(A, i) = A[mod1(i, length(A))]
```

Or even your own mod-indexed array type:

```
julia> immutable CircArray{T} <: AbstractArray{T,1}
           xs::Vector{T}
       end

julia> Base.size(x::CircArray) = (length(x.xs),)

julia> Base.getindex(x::CircArray, i) = x.xs[mod1(i, length(x.xs))]

julia> A = CircArray([1:2:10;])
CircArray{Array{Int64,1}}([1,3,5,7,9])

julia> A[0]
9

julia> A[5]
9

julia> A[7]
3
```

It is not too difficult to implement slicing on top of this. As DNF mentioned in a comment, a clean and concise solution is

```
modindex(A, i) = A[mod1.(i, end)]
```

or the equivalent for `getindex`, which handles both scalar indexing and slicing.

---

Edit: Since your question mentioned iteration, I figure I'd provide a more general solution that also works on non-arrays for iteration purposes, using only the functional iterables in `Base`:

```
julia> threes(A) = let cy = cycle(A)
           take(zip(cy, drop(cy, 1), drop(cy, 2)), length(A))
       end
threes (generic function with 1 method)

julia> for (a, b, c) in threes([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
           println(a, b, c)
       end
123
234
345
451
512
```

Comment: A clean solution could be `modindex(A, i) = A[mod1.(i, end)]`. It's super terse and you can do slicing.

Comment: Great answer, just what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: In the definition of `CircArray` shouldn't `T` in the superclass be replaced by the parameter of `T`? (or the parameter refactored to be the `eltype` of the array, with additional `Vector` modifier to `xs`)

Answer (score 4):

[Iterators.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Iterators.jl) will give you the **simple iterator** to *"accessing an array some elements at a time"*:

```
julia> for i in partition(1:15, 3, 1)
          @show i
       end
i = (1,2,3)
i = (2,3,4)
i = (3,4,5)
i = (4,5,6)
i = (5,6,7)
i = (6,7,8)
i = (7,8,9)
i = (8,9,10)
i = (9,10,11)
i = (10,11,12)
i = (11,12,13)
i = (12,13,14)
i = (13,14,15)
```

and as FengYang Wang suggested, the `mod1` function does the *"wrapping round to the beginning"* job. just make a combination:

```
julia> for i in partition(1:15, 3, 1)
          @show mod1.(collect(i), 10)
       end
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [1,2,3]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [2,3,4]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [3,4,5]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [4,5,6]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [5,6,7]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [6,7,8]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [7,8,9]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [8,9,10]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [9,10,1]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [10,1,2]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [1,2,3]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [2,3,4]
mod1.(collect(i),10) = [3,4,5]
```

Comment: You can also consider using `cycle` on the iterator, then `take`ing the result. I incorporated a similar solution into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

do

```
 repmat(a',5,2)
 5x10 Array{Int64,2}:
  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5
  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5
  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5
  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5
  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5
```

and then

```
map(i -> [a[i,i], a[i,i+1], a[i,i+2]], 1:5)
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[3,4,5]
[4,5,1]
[5,1,2]
```

**Bonus**

If you wanna over engineer this, or memory is an issue (repmat is not exactly memory efficient)

```
s = size(a)[2]

l(i,v) = i + v > s ? i + v - s : i + v

map(i -> [a[i,i], a[i, l(i,1)], a[i, l(i,2)]], 1:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just define it yourself? Like:

```
a = repmat(collect(1:10)', 10)
sza = size(a,1) #here 10
for i in 1:sza
   toget = collect(i:i+2)
   toget[toget.>sza] -= sza
   println(a[i, toget])
end
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[3,4,5]
[4,5,6]
[5,6,7]
[6,7,8]
[7,8,9]
[8,9,10]
[9,10,1]
[10,1,2]
```

Where `println` could be whatever you want?